# DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH & DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES not working

Tags: c, macos, osx-elcapitan

I create a .dylib file and compile it:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static void* (*real_malloc)(size_t);

void *malloc(size_t size)
{
    void *p = NULL;
    fprintf(stderr, "malloc(%zd) = ", size);
    p = real_malloc(size);
    fprintf(stderr, "%p\n", p);
    return p;
}

void __attribute((constructor))init()
{
    real_malloc = (decltype(real_malloc))dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "malloc");
    if (NULL == real_malloc) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error in `dlsym`: %s\n", dlerror());
        return;
    }
}
```

Then I create a test program that calls `malloc`. I made sure the call to malloc is not optimized out.

Next I ran the following:

`DYLD_PRINT_LIBRARIES=1 X=1 DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES=./libTestHook.dylib ./malloctest`

It loads it but it does NOT hook the function at all.. Any ideas? I tried this code before El Capitan upgrade and it used to work.. I also made the malloc throw an exception just to see if it was being called. It's not.

What am I missing?

The results were:

```
sh-3.2# DYLD_PRINT_LIBRARIES=1 X=1 DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES=./libTestHook.dylib ./malloctest clear
dyld: loaded: /Users/Brandon/Desktop/./malloctest
dyld: loaded: ./libTestHook.dylib
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/system/libcompiler_rt.dylib
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/system/libcorecrypto.dylib
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/system/libkeymgr.dylib
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/system/libquarantine.dylib
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/system/libsystem_asl.dylib
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/system/libsystem_configuration.dylib
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/system/libsystem_coreservices.dylib
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/system/libsystem_coretls.dylib
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/system/libsystem_m.dylib
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/system/libsystem_malloc.dylib
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/system/libsystem_network.dylib
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/system/libsystem_networkextension.dylib
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/system/libsystem_notify.dylib
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/system/libsystem_secinit.dylib
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/system/libsystem_trace.dylib
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/system/libunc.dylib
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/system/libunwind.dylib
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/libauto.dylib
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/libDiagnosticMessagesClient.dylib
A
B
C
D
```

Comment: I have a question here - if I do a dyld_interpose for say `malloc` in a static library and then link it as a dependency of another static library, will it interpose the `malloc` calls in the other library as well?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The code in my original post used to work on Yosemite. On El Capitan, it does NOT work. I ended up doing the following approach (`DYLD_INTERPOSE` + `DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES`):

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


#define DYLD_INTERPOSE(_replacment,_replacee) \
__attribute__((used)) static struct{ const void* replacment; const void* replacee; } _interpose_##_replacee \
__attribute__ ((section ("__DATA,__interpose"))) = { (const void*)(unsigned long)&_replacment, (const void*)(unsigned long)&_replacee };


void* pMalloc(size_t size) //would be nice if I didn't have to rename my function..
{
   printf("Allocated: %zu\n", size);
   return malloc(size);
}

DYLD_INTERPOSE(pMalloc, malloc);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for you answer :)

Comment: It seems this answer came from http://stackoverflow.com/a/20717262/1027966.

Comment: Close, but it didn't come from there though. I was looking up how to "hook functions on OSX" and came across LD_PRELOAD and DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES and since neither worked, I looked up how to do `code injection` on OSX and came across a Google Forums post for `DYLD_INTERPOSE`. Funny enough, it didn't work until I combined both ideas.

Answer (score 6):

From `dyld` docs:

> DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES
>                 This is a colon separated list of dynamic libraries to load before the ones specified in the program.  This lets you test new  modules  of  existing
>                 dynamic  shared libraries that are used in flat-namespace images by loading a temporary dynamic shared library with just the new modules.  Note that
>                 this has no effect on images built a two-level namespace images using a dynamic shared library unless DYLD_FORCE_FLAT_NAMESPACE is also used.
>
> DYLD_FORCE_FLAT_NAMESPACE
>                 Force all images in the program to be linked as flat-namespace images and ignore any two-level namespace bindings.  This may cause programs to  fail
>                 to execute with a multiply defined symbol error if two-level namespace images are used to allow the images to have multiply defined symbols.

So your code needed DYLD_FORCE_FLAT_NAMESPACE=1. Anyway, [my implementation](https://github.com/vmarkovtsev/hack_malloc) works for `/usr/local/bin/git` only with this option enabled.

Comment: Except you're testing on your own program. Try this on Safari or any program that uses functions from /System/Library and replace any of the functions. Guaranteed it won't work.

http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/193368/what-is-the-rootless-feature-in-el-capitan-really

Comment: When trying this, I get a segfault off the bat.

Answer (score 6):

If you can recompile the executable being hooked, then I think a simpler solution is to recompile the executable with `-force_flat_namespace`:

```
➜  clang slow_leak.c -force_flat_namespace -o slow_leak
➜  DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES=malloc_hook.dylib ./slow_leak
leaking
in hooked malloc
```

[More info](https://glandium.org/blog/?p=2764).  This is on OSX 10.12.2 MacOS Sierra.

[A comment on HN](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=19190343) (2 years later) mentioned `DYLD_FORCE_FLAT_NAMESPACE=1` can help in cases where it's not feasible to recompile.  I haven't tried it yet, so YMMV.

Comment: Thanks!  This worked for me: `DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES=libshim.dylib DYLD_FORCE_FLAT_NAMESPACE=1 ./C_Playground`

Answer (score 2):

Please try to export any DYLD environment variable, f.e.:

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=.
```

Check env:

```
env
```

If variable wasn't exported, try to [disable system integrity protection](https://osxdaily.com/2015/10/05/disable-rootless-system-integrity-protection-mac-os-x/) (also [this link](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/210817/disable-system-integrity-protection-on-os-x-running-on-vmware) may be useful if you are running on MacOS virtual machine)