# Function interposition, mark C function to always use symbol stub instead of direct call

Tags: c, macos, linker, stub, mach-o

A fun academic problem I am trying to solve:

In C code, I am trying to dynamically rebind symbols at runtime, much like [Facebook's fishhook repo](https://github.com/facebook/fishhook) which rebinds function symbols. I mainly care about, going after symbols referenced in the `__DATA.__la_symbol_ptr` section of a Mach-O executable. With the fishhook implementation, you provide your new function to replace the original one, a string indicating which function you want to replace, as well as a global function pointer which will take the place to call the original, replaced function.

For example, taken from the README in the fishhook repo...

```
static int (*orig_close)(int);
int my_close(int fd) {
    return orig_close(fd);
}
```

... then in `main`

```
rebind_symbols((struct rebinding[1]){{"close", my_close, (void *)&orig_close}}, 1);
```

This is awesome, but I want be able to completely switch all calls to `my_close` with all calls to `close` and vice versa in my module. For example, instead of a global function pointer that points to the original `close`, I'd want my implementation to look like this:

```
int my_close(int fd) {
    return my_close(fd);
}
```

Unfortunately, since this symbol is referenced in the same module, this symbol will get called via a direct call instead of a symbol stub.  Here's the assembly when calling this function from `main`

```
0x100001e00 <+0>:  push   rbp
0x100001e01 <+1>:  mov    rbp, rsp
0x100001e04 <+4>:  sub    rsp, 0x20
0x100001e08 <+8>:  xor    eax, eax
0x100001e0a <+10>: mov    dword ptr [rbp - 0x4], 0x0
0x100001e11 <+17>: mov    dword ptr [rbp - 0x8], edi
0x100001e14 <+20>: mov    qword ptr [rbp - 0x10], rsi
0x100001e18 <+24>: mov    edi, eax
0x100001e1a <+26>: call   0x100001da0               ; my_close at main.m:42
0x100001e1f <+31>: xor    edi, edi
0x100001e21 <+33>: mov    dword ptr [rbp - 0x14], eax
0x100001e24 <+36>: mov    eax, edi
0x100001e26 <+38>: add    rsp, 0x20
0x100001e2a <+42>: pop    rbp
0x100001e2b <+43>: ret
```

Ok, easy enough fix, I can use an assembler directive to mark the function as weak and use a weakref to shut the compiler up about a potential stack overflow. Changing `my_close` to:

```
static int f(int) __attribute__ ((weakref ("my_close")));

__attribute__((weak))
int my_close(int fd) {
    return f(fd);
}
```

Will then produce the following assembly in `main`:

```
0x100001df0 <+0>:  push   rbp
0x100001df1 <+1>:  mov    rbp, rsp
0x100001df4 <+4>:  sub    rsp, 0x20
0x100001df8 <+8>:  xor    eax, eax
0x100001dfa <+10>: mov    dword ptr [rbp - 0x4], 0x0
0x100001e01 <+17>: mov    dword ptr [rbp - 0x8], edi
0x100001e04 <+20>: mov    qword ptr [rbp - 0x10], rsi
0x100001e08 <+24>: mov    edi, eax
0x100001e0a <+26>: call   0x100001e5e               ; symbol stub for: my_close
0x100001e0f <+31>: xor    edi, edi
0x100001e11 <+33>: mov    dword ptr [rbp - 0x14], eax
0x100001e14 <+36>: mov    eax, edi
0x100001e16 <+38>: add    rsp, 0x20
0x100001e1a <+42>: pop    rbp
0x100001e1b <+43>: ret
```

So here's the part I am stuck on: when referencing `my_close` inside `my_close`, it always results in a direct call. For example: here's the assembly for `my_close`

```
0x100001dd0 <+0>:  push   rbp
0x100001dd1 <+1>:  mov    rbp, rsp
0x100001dd4 <+4>:  sub    rsp, 0x10
0x100001dd8 <+8>:  mov    dword ptr [rbp - 0x4], edi
0x100001ddb <+11>: mov    edi, dword ptr [rbp - 0x4]
0x100001dde <+14>: call   0x100001dd0               ; <+0> at main.m:44
0x100001de3 <+19>: add    rsp, 0x10
0x100001de7 <+23>: pop    rbp
0x100001de8 <+24>: ret
```

Is there any assembler directives I can use (that I've missed) to tell `my_close` to be treated as a stub when being called inside `my_close`? Yeah, I know I can use `dlsym` to get the original, but I am being stubborn :]

Comment: And looking back at the `weakref` `__attribute__` that seems like that couldn't work no matter what once since the function needs to be declared as static. I'll leave the question as is though.

Comment: Just a thought... why not declare `my_call` as a global function pointer type (maybe even using the `volatile` attribute and preferably making sure it's atomic and aligned), so every reference to the symbol is actually a reference to the global variable (which you can update at any moment)....?

Comment: For an alternative route you may be interested in this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34120249/5329717

Comment: @Kamil.S that's a solution and follows the no-global pointer/dlsym restriction I put on this question.  If you want to pull out your response to a reply, I'll mark that as correct along w/ the bounty

Comment: @Sozin'sComet thanks, but that'd be kinda unfair as I didn't come up with it, merely found it a while back.

Comment: @Kamil.S Fair enough, well thanks again for your help on this

Answer (score 0):

Following my comment, here's one possible implementation where `my_call` is declared as a global function pointer type.

This approach means that every reference to the symbol is actually a reference to the global variable (a function pointer) that can be easily updated at any moment.

Place this in `my_close.h`:

```
extern volatile int (*my_close)(int);

void set_my_close(int (*func)(int));
```

and add this `my_call.c` to your project (mostly untested):

```
#if defined(__unix__) || defined(__APPLE__) || defined(__linux__)
#ifndef _GNU_SOURCE
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#endif
#endif /* __unix__ */

/* Select the correct compiler builtin method. */
#if defined(__has_builtin)

#if __has_builtin(__atomic_exchange_n)
#define EXCHANGE(...) __atomic_exchange_n(__VA_ARGS__, __ATOMIC_ACQ_REL)

#elif __has_builtin(__sync_swap)
#define EXCHANGE(...) __sync_swap(__VA_ARGS__)

#else
#error Required builtin "__sync_swap" or "__atomic_exchange_n" missing from compiler.
#endif /* defined(__has_builtin) */

#elif __GNUC__ > 3
#define EXCHANGE(...) __sync_fetch_and_or(__VA_ARGS__)

#else
#error Required builtin "__sync_swap" or "__atomic_exchange_n" not found.
#endif

volatile int (*my_close)(int);

void set_my_close(int (*func)(int)) { EXCHANGE(&my_close, func); }
```

This makes it easy to update the `my_close` and route it to different functions dynamically.

...

An alternate option, which utilizes C11 Atomic operations (supposedly more portable) will probably require `my_close.h` to be included in any source file calling `my_close` (to make sure `atomic_load` is called).

The following is untested:

in `my_close.h`:

```
#include <stdatomic.h>

extern volatile _Atomic int (*my_close)(int);

inline void set_my_close(int (*func)(int)) { atomic_store(&my_close, func); }

#define my_close(fd) ((atomic_load(&my_close))( fd ))
```

in `my_close.c`:

```
#include "my_close.h"

#undef my_close

volatile _Atomic int (*my_close)(int);
```

I didn't run or lint any of the code on my computer, so please consider this as an outline only.

Answer (score 0):

For dyld imported functions it's possible to replace the called address in runtime. The following code relies on dyld stub addresses being at the beginning of `__DATA` segment followed by global variables. The code snippet here performs a backward search starting from a global variable address.

```
size_t (*orgStrlenPtr)(const char *__s);
size_t myStrlen(const char *__s)
{
    return orgStrlenPtr(__s);
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    char *ptr = &orgStrlenPtr;
    while (*(void**)ptr != strlen) {
        ptr--;
    }
    orgStrlenPtr = *(void **)ptr;
    *(void **)ptr = myStrlen;
}
```